# Creation of string from list with sublists with python

Tags: python, string, list, file, sublist

I'm trying to create a string from a list with sublists.
I have something like this:

```
list = [[1234],[4567],[7890]]
```

At the end, I would like to get an output that I will be able to copy to the file that will look exactly like that (each sublist in a separate row):

```
1234
4567
7890
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
for s in list:
    for i in s:
        mystring +=i
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to override builtins(like `list`) with your own stuff... Also, what exactly is not working? Errors? Or it doesn't work as intended?

Answer (score 2):

Expected Result:
join ALL the values in the list into a single string, but each substring on a different line.

> off topic tip: never use `list` as an name object!

So a simple way to do it is to work with a list comprehension:

```
lst = [[1234],[4567],[7890]]

lst = [str(item) for sublist in lst for item in sublist]

print('\n'.join(lst))
```

The result is this string:

```
1234
4567
7890
```

If there is more than one value in each sublist and you need each sublist on a different line, then you must choose some divisor (in this case I used a comma), so it will look like this:

```
lst = [[1234,123],[4567],[7890]]

list_strings_sublist = []

for sublist in lst:
    new_sublist = [str(x) for x in sublist]
    list_strings_sublist.append(','.join(new_sublist))

print('\n'.join(list_strings_sublist))
```

The result is this string:

```
1234,123
4567
7890
```

A test to see if it really became a single string, let's do it:

```
final_string = 'This is one test: ' + '\n'.join(list_strings_sublist) + ' and the unique string to all values is created.'
print(final_string)
```

The result is:

```
This is one test: 1234,123
4567
7890 and the unique string to all values is created.
```

Comment: @kenntnisse It outputs the same as your answer, mind explaining why Brondby's isnt working for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [[1234],[4567, 999],[7890]] # don't want to use list
for sublist in lst: #goes through each sublist
    for item in sublist: #goes through each item
        print(item, end = " ") #so each item is on the same line
    print() # to get a new line
```

outputs

```
1234 
4567 999 
7890
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comphresion:

```py
list = [[1234],[4567],[7890]]

list = [item for sublist in list for item in sublist]

for z in list:
    print(z)
```

Outputs:

```
1234
4567
7890
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `list = [[1234],[4567,999],[7890]]`.

Answer (score 0):

i agree to go with list comprehension. however if you want the output to be a single string instead you might wanna go with the join() function.

```py
list = [[1234],[4567],[7890]]

mystring = "".join([str(*x)+"\n" for x in list])

print(mystring)
```

Output:

```py
1234
4567
7890
```

Comment: This only works if each sub-list contains just one element. Agreed that that's what the question shows but there are simpler more flexible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Similar to some of the other answers but a slightly different way:

```
list = [[1234],[4567],[7890]]
string_nums = "\n".join([str(item) for lst in list for item in lst])
print(string_nums)
```